# Trying to write data from apache spark to snowflake table

Tags: azure, apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, databricks

I am trying to write data from Apache spark to snowflake table, I removed all datetime fields to reduce the complexity. Still i am getting below error when writing a "`String`" field in Apache Spark to "`varchar`" field in snowflake.

I verified length of the column and that is not a problem. Any suggestion on how to debug this? Below is the error i am getting. Thanks in advance

```
Error: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 150
```

Comment: Please add pyspark code in question which showing error also good to share your snowflake schema.